# Clone a component that has already been mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build an app that uses drag-and-drop behaviour, and the component being dragged needs to be cloned elsewhere in the DOM. Since the component is already mounted, trying to mount it again causes the browser to hang.

Trying to use `cloneWithProps` results in a `Cannot read property 'defaultProps' of undefined` error.

Here's a testcase:

```
var TestCase = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      draggingItem: null
    }
  },

  render () {
    return <div>
      <ExampleComponent onClick={this.setDraggingItem} />
      {this.state.draggingItem}
    </div>
  },

  setDraggingItem (component) {
    // This gives `Cannot read property 'defaultProps' of undefined`
    //React.addons.cloneWithProps(component)

    // This crashes the browser
    //this.setState({ draggingItem: component })
  }
})

var ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return <div onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Hello World</div>
  },

  handleOnClick (event) {
    this.props.onClick(this)
  }
})

React.render(<TestCase />, document.body)
```

Of course I could simply clone `component.getDOMNode()` in `setDraggingItem`, but it really seems like rendering the component or calling `cloneWithProps` should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two things you need to create an element is: the component class (e.g. ExampleComponent) and its props.  cloneWithProps is only to be used in `render` and only with an element coming from props which was created in another component's render.  You shouldn't save elements, or pass them around other than to other components in render.  Instead, you pass around objects (props) and component classes.

Since you need to know the props and component class to render it in the first place, you can handle all of this in TestCase.

```js
var TestCase = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      draggingItem: null,
      draggingItemProps: null
    }
  },

  render () {
    return <div>
      <ExampleComponent onClick={this.setDraggingItem.bind(null, 
      /* the component class */         ExampleComponent, 
      /* the props to render it with */ null
      )} />
      { 
        this.state.draggingItem && React.createElement(
          this.state.draggingItem, 
          this.state.draggingItemProps
        )
      }
    </div>
  },

  setDraggingItem (component, props, event) {
    this.setState({ draggingItem: component, draggingItemProps: props })
  }
});

var ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return <div onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Hello World</div>
  },
  // just defer the event
  handleOnClick (event) {
    this.props.onClick(event)
  }
});
```

If you wish to make these valid outside this TestCase component, ensure there aren't any functions bound to TestCase in the props.  Also ensure there's no children prop with react elements in it.  If children are relevant, provide the `{componentClass,props}` structure needed to recreate them.

It's hard to tell what your actual requirements are, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Ah, this seems pretty perfect. And it answers what would have been my next question of accessing statics from a mounted component (you wouldn't, just use the reference to the component). Thankfully children aren't involved and I don't need `this.state.draggingItemProps`.

Answer (score 1):

You need be sure you're creating a new component with the same props, not mount the same one multiple times. First, setup a function that returns an instantiated components (easier to drop JSX here):

```
function getComponent(props) {
   return ExampleComponent(props);
}
```

Then in your TestCase render:

```
return (<div>
    { getComponent({ onClick: this.setDraggingItem }) }
    { this.state.draggingItem }
</div>);
```

That will create the first component. Then to create a clone:

```
setDraggingItem(component) {
    var clone = getComponent(component.props);
}
```

This deals with the cloning part. You still have some dragging and rendering to figure out.

Comment: In 0.12+ it's `React.createElement(ExampleComponent, props)`.